# Why aren't my images downloading into ImageViews?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm pretty new to native Android development. What my app is currently doing:

1. Download a `JSON` of image urls from our server
2. Add an `ImageView` to a `ListView` for each image

I've gotten the `JSON` and am now working on using an `ImageAdapter` (extends `BaseAdapter`) to populate the `ListView`, but I'm running into an error:

- I'm getting `println needs a message` during creation of the `InputStream` in my `OpenHttpGETConnection` function.

Here's my code (in order of highest to lowest with unnecessary code removed):

1. Once JSON Is loaded my `onPostExecute` code'll run to start the adapter:

   ```
   private class DownloadImagesTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
           return getImages(urls[0]);
       }

       @Override
       protected  void onPostExecute(String result){
           JSONArray images = null;
           images = new JSONArray(result);

           // TURN images into array of imageviews
           ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   @here---->   listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(), images));
           Log.d("DownloadTextTask", images.toString());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here's my `ImageAdapter` code:

   ```
   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       private Context context;
       private JSONArray images;
       public ImageAdapter(Context c, JSONArray i){
           context = c;
           images = i;
       }
       // returns an imageview view
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
           try {
               String url = "http://www.example.com/" + images.get(position);
   @here---->  imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(url));
           } catch (Exception e){
               Log.d("LoadImage", e.getLocalizedMessage());
           }
           imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

           return imageView;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Here's my `getImageBitmap` function:

   ```
   private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url){
       Bitmap bitmap = null;
       InputStream in = null;
       try {

   @here---->  in = OpenHttpGETConnection(url);

       } catch (Exception e) { 

   @i_get
   @this ---->  Log.wtf("OpenGET", e.getMessage() + ": " + url ); 
   @error

       }
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
       in.close();

       return bitmap;
   }
   ```
4. And finally, here's my `OpenHttpGETConnection` function:

   ```
   public static InputStream OpenHttpGETConnection(String url){
       InputStream inputStream = null;
       HttpClient httpClient = null;
       HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


       httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
       inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

       return inputStream;
   }
   ```
5. And here's the pertaining `LogCat` line: (Happens for 3 images that came through the JSON file)

   ```
   A/OpenGET﹕ println needs a message: http://www.example.com/image1.jpg
   ```

The weird thing is, I use the same `OpenHttpGETConnection` when I load my JSON data, so I'm pretty sure that's returning a correct `InputStream` object. Are there some caveats when using it for text vs. binary data (jpg)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in the adapter, in the `getView()` method, you're not recycling the items. Have a look on the ViewHolder pattern (http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).
Then, `getImageBitmap()` seems to be executed on the same thread, I wonder why it doesn't crash. I guess there you download the actual image. It should be done asynchronously, and you should send a reference of the `ImageView` and when the download is finished you should load it into it. Of course you'll have to care about if when you put the `bitmap` inside the `ImageView` you have the good `ImageView` on the screen (because it might have been recycled).
To get rid of all these concerns you could just use `Picasso library` (http://square.github.io/picasso/) and that will do all this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This picasso library is a god-send for someone new to Android development like me, it worked like charm!